# Use of I as personal pronoun in interface names

Tags: c#, interface, naming-conventions

Back in my COM days, it was common to use the I in interface names as a personal pronoun, as if the object was describing what it could do. ie:

```
IProvideData
```

Is this still the case in the world of .Net, or it is now preffered to use the third person:

```
IDataProvider
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoted from the naming guidelines:

> Do name classes, interfaces, and value types with nouns, noun phrases,
>   or occasionally adjective phrases

Given that, `IDataProvider` seems like a better name than `IProvideData`. I find it more logical, especially when paired with member names. `IDataProvider.GetData` seems more natural to me than `IProvideData.GetData`.

Read more in [Names of Classes, Structs, and Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229040.aspx) in the [Design Guidelines for Developing Class Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

I'd stick to the third person for naming interfaces in c#

Answer (score 3):

Mostly people prefer using the third person convention.

Name of interface is not a sentence; it is a adjective, usually given to classes, to depict what they are capable of.

Hence the third person is the class implementing the interface.